# Open original image when a thumb image is clicked

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, graphicimage

Displaying images using `<p:graphicImage>` as follows.

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{imageBean.image}" width="80" height="60">
    <f:param name="id" value="1"/>
    <f:param name="width" value="80"/>
    <f:param name="height" value="60"/>
</p:graphicImage>
```

The `ImageBean` looks like the following.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImageBean {

    @Inject
    private Service service;

    public ImageBean () {}

    public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else {
            Map<String, String> requestParameterMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
            String id = requestParameterMap.get("id");
            String widthParam = requestParameterMap.get("width");
            String heightParam = requestParameterMap.get("height");

            int width = Utils.isNumber(widthParam) ? Integer.parseInt(widthParam) : -1;
            int height = Utils.isNumber(heightParam) ? Integer.parseInt(heightParam) : -1;

            byte[] bytes = Utils.isNumber(id) ? service.findImageById(Long.parseLong(id), width, height) : null;
            return bytes == null ? null : new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        }
    }
}
```

The `service.findImageById()` method returns a `byte[]` obtained after resizing the given image according to the dimentions given.

This will display a thumb image after being resized on the server side according to the dimensions given.

`<p:graphicImage>` generates an image URL dynamically which is to be assigned to `src` of the generated `<img>` tag. This would look something like the following.

```
/ContextPath/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=5.3&amp;pfdrid=aAPHlxcQ2lcqfvzacYoCC6iUxLU1VVFp&amp;pfdrt=sc&amp;id=9&amp;height=100&amp;width=100&amp;pfdrid_c=true
```

---

Is it possible to open the original image in a new tab, when a thumb image is clicked so that it can correspond to the HTML something like the following?

```
<a href="show_original_image.php?id=1" target="_blank">
    <img src="show_thumb_image.php?id=1" width="80" height="60" style="border: 0px none;"/>
</a>
```

What would be the value of `href` of `<a>` and how it is to be assigned to `href` dynamically in the context of JSF / PrimeFaces?

Comment: You could use a `servlet` to render the image and send the image-id by GET parameter, then use the service go get the byte[] and then have the servlet print the content

Comment: I thought of that before posting but designing a Servlet every time a different set of images is needed is something not very maintenance-friendly.

Comment: Is this helpful in solving your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736390 Or do you need a PrimeFaces specific solution (hack/workaround)?

Comment: @BalusC : That is undoubtedly helpful but currently I don't want to modify the existing project which has been using `<p:graphicImage>` at many places since the beginning. I will take that for future projects, if any.

Comment: Clear. Maybe I'll look if time allows me.